# newbie c# cannot implicitly convert type

Tags: c#

I am new to coding and trying to learn through various internet tutorials.  At this point I'm working on C# in .net.  Far too often I follow a tutorial, replicate it, run it and get errors and don't know where to turn.  I'm reaching out here for some tips.  I'm trying to run the following and I'm getting the error:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox', in relation to the line stating:
>   richTextBox1 = sr.ReadToEnd();

Full code is:

```
    using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url = textBox1.Text;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            richTextBox1 = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the reason for you error is because a "string" is not a "RichTextBox". You cannot assign `richTextBox1` to a string because it just doesn't make sense. You need to assign `richTextBox1`'s Text property to `sr.ReadToEnd()` which makes sense because the Text property is of type "string"

Comment: this is a simple error.. perhaps you should read up on TextBox Property's one of them being the `.Text` Property.. change `richTextBox1` to `richTextBox1.Text`

Comment: This may have worked in classic VB that had default properties, but you have to specify the Text property as @BlakeThingstad noted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look my friend we have to specify the property name otherwise it will think you want to change the object it self so just add " .Text" to the "richTextBox1"

```
richTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Second better for any text value to append in the end with ".ToString();"

Ask as you wish and go on.

Comment: Thank you.  That was very helpful and I understand it better now.

Comment: any time :-) you welcome

Answer (score 1):

You have to access the 'text' property of the RichTextbox control like so

```
richTextbox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

And also I would recommend that you encapsulate your IDisposable objects into an 'using' block like:

```
using(Streamreader sr = new Streamreader(ObjectToGetAStringFrom))
{
richTextBox.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

That way you won't run into problems when you don't call the sr.Close(); function and it's also considered good practice. Hope it helps and good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer and the tip.  I appreciate it!

Comment: @STLPete You are totally welcome. I remember when I was first learning C# too and boy was it tough comming from C